# The 'code_challange' is not added to a request while using custom provider in NextAuth

Tags: next.js, oauth, next-auth, pkce

This is my first time using NextAuth and actually implementing any OAuth authentication in an app so it's possible I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure it out. I have to implement authentication with PKCE by a custom provider. My config looks like this:

```
{
  id: 'providerName',
  name: 'providerName',
  type: 'oauth',
  clientId: CLIENT_ID,
  wellKnown: WELL_KNOWN_URI,
  profile(profile) {
    console.log(profile);
    return {
      id: profile.sub,
      name: profile.name,
      email: profile.email,
      image: profile.picture,
    };
  },
  authorization: {
    params: {
      redirect_uri: `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/providerName`,
      checks: ['pkce', 'state', 'nonce'],
      prompt: 'select_account',
      scope: 'openid email phone profile',
    },
  },
}
```

Now I'm getting an error in my Nextjs app terminal: `invalid_request` `Authorization Server policy requires PKCE to be used for this request`

From what I understand, `code_challange` and `code_challange_method` should be appended automatically by NextAuth (please correct me if I'm wrong), so why those parameters are not added to a request? Or is there someting else wrong in this config?

I'm using Next 13.4.10 and NextAuth 4.22.5

I'm browsing NextAuth docs and issues but with no luck.